# Not able to select and upload a file with robot framework

Tags: file-upload, robotframework

I am trying to browse, select and upload the file for my test application using robot framework test automation. I have tried the below mentioned code. It's not working. Please help me on this.

I tried this-

```
Choose File //span[contains(text(), 'Browse')]  C:/Automation/Data/Test File.txt
Click Button    id=btnupload
```

the HTML Code is -

```
<div class="panel-footer" style="">
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file" style="">
Browse 
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" style=""/>
</span>
<button id="btnupload" class="btn btn-default" disabled="" onclick="sendFile()" type="button">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"/>
Upload
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Why isn't it working? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: There is no error. The keyword 'Choose File' executed successfully. But, the file is not browsed and uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many hit and trial, at last i found the working set of code. It's mentioned below:

`Choose File id=file C:\\Automation\\Data\\Test File.txt
Click Button    id=btnupload`